# How to understand Linux versions

Tags: kernel

I'm considering purchasing an expensive board and SDK that "works with Linux" which I've learned to my cost to mean "works with some Linux".  The vendor has asked which kernel version I have.  Using uname -r I get 3.5.0-47 generic with my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I just read that Ubuntu 14.04 generic will release with Linux 3.3 which appears to be an earlier version.

Does this really mean that the latest Ubuntu uses an earlier Linux than an earlier Ubuntu?

I'm confused.

Comment: Where did you read 14.04 would ship with 3.3? That's silly. My Trusty VM has 3.13. A quick Google confirms that Trusty will most likely ship with 3.13.

Comment: As of today, 3.13 will be the official kernel version for 14.04

Comment: they are asking if you are going to be using fedora,ubuntu, centos or suse (or any derivative of those or some niche OS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a vendor asks *what version of Linux* you have, it is very plausible that what they mean by *version* is in fact *distribution*. In this case, if you are on Ubuntu 12.04, then that is what you should reply with.

If they specifically want the version *number* for the Linux *kernel* they will generally be more specific in stating so.

Comment: Yes, they, and I, meant the kernel version.  I should be more careful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with what version of linux will the stable version of Ubuntu 14.04 released, but I can address the version confusion.  This is something I recently came to know about: Read each minor version numbers as integers even after each decimal point.

So, version `3.15` > `3.2`. How? Simply because 15 > 2.